# Atribuindo um estilo CSS a um elemento específico dentro de uma div

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Olá!

Estou fazendo um projeto e eu tenho uma div `flexbox-container` que tem três div filhas, `card-home-main`.

Gostaria de fazer um efeito ao passar o mouse na `card-home-main`, mas quando eu faço isso, ao passar o mouse em um, todas as outras duas também recebem o efeito simultaneamente. Além disso, todas as divs dentro de `card-home-main` também recebem o efeito, de modo que se, ao passar o mouse em cima de uma imagem dentro dela, a imagem em si irá receber o efeito.

Como fazer para limitar que apenas a div cujo o mouse está em cima, receba o efeito por vez? E também limitar que os componentes dentro dela não o recebam.

Deixei um exemplo do que eu estou fazendo no exemplo abaixo

```css
.div-rectangle-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 492px;
  background: linear-gradient(192deg, #3D4554 -10.36%, #242B36 45.63%, #1D1D1D 117.21%);
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-logo {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 79px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  width: 250px;
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-title {
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-top: 36px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2CC3D5;
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-subtitle {
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-subtitle .main-subsubtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -9%;
  margin-left: 5.8%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #EAEEEE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.15);
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: height 1000ms;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 0.8%;
}

.flexbox-container :hover {
  height: 400px;
}

.card-home-main .card-img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.section-icon-circle-card {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  padding: 18px;
  margin-top: 4.95%;
  margin-bottom: 4.95%;
  margin-left: 6.42%;
}

.section-icon-circle-card--bot {
  background: rgba(44, 195, 213, 0.2);
}

.section-icon-circle-card--watermelon {
  background: rgba(246, 102, 137, 0.2)
}

.section-icon-circle-card--warning {
  background: rgba(255, 207, 51, 0.2);
}

.card-home-main .card-info {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  padding-top: 0%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-title {
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #607B99;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-icon {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-text {
  display: none;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #3D4554;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-text-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.buttton-card:hover {
  background: #2498A8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="div-rectangle-main">
    <h1 class="main-title"> Lore lore lore!</h1>
    <div class="main-subtitle">
      lore lore lore
      <p class="main-subsubtitle">lore lore lore lore =)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="card-home-main" id="card1">
      <div class="card-img">
        <div class="section-icon-circle-card section-icon-circle-card--bot">
          <img src="img/illustrations/Estrela-1.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-info">
        <div class="card-title">
          <h3>Basico</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text">lore lore lore.</p>
        <div class="card-icon">
          <BlipIcon name="arrow-ball-down-solid" class="bp-fs-1 bp-fill-bot"></BlipIcon>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text-mobile">lore lore lore</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-home-main" id="card2">
      <div class="card-img">
        <div class="section-icon-circle-card section-icon-circle-card--watermelon">
          <img src="img/illustrations/Estrela-2.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-info">
        <div class="card-title">
          <h3>Inter</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-icon">
          <BlipIcon name="arrow-ball-down-solid" class="bp-fs-1 bp-fill-bot"></BlipIcon>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text">lore lore lore.</p>
        <p class="card-text-mobile">Lore lore lore.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-home-main" id="card3">
      <div class="card-img">
        <div class="section-icon-circle-card section-icon-circle-card--warning">
          <img src="img/illustrations/Estrela-3.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-info">
        <div class="card-title">
          <h3>Avan</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-icon">
          <BlipIcon name="arrow-ball-down-solid" class="bp-fs-1 bp-fill-bot"></BlipIcon>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text">Lore lore lore</p>
        <p class="card-text-mobile">lore lore lore lore</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao fazer `.flexbox-container :hover` você irá aplicar a qualquer elemento dentro de `.flexbox-container`, você precisa especificar que tipo de elemento que deve receber o efeito, use `.flexbox-container card-home-main:hover`

Adicione `align-items: start;` no `.flexbox-container` para que apenas o elemento que receber o `:hover` aumente. Isso por que, por padrão, o flexbox deixa os elementos filhos com a mesma altura

Comment: Eu tinha essa noção, mas não sabia como resolver. Obrigado, o `align-items: start;` funcionou!

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, aceite ela clicando no ✓