# Efeitos de hover acontecendo automaticamente em @media

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-hover

Olá!

Estou fazendo um efeito de hover no meu projeto ([Atribuindo um estilo CSS a um elemento específico dentro de uma div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399655/atribuindo-um-estilo-css-a-um-elemento-espec%c3%adfico-dentro-de-uma-div#399657)), em caixas, que quando eu passo o mouse ela se expande e exibe um texto e um botão que não existiam antes do efeito acontecer.

O problema é que quando eu mudo o site para a versão *mobile*, esses efeitos de aparecer o texto e o botão ficam acontecendo infinitamente. Eles nem deveriam aparecer na versão movel, alías.

O código: 
https://jsfiddle.net/brikohler/86rgnsLx/16/

Alguém sabe me dizer como anular esses efeitos de hover?

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 2px) and (max-device-width: 736px) {

 .div-forum-ideas-text {
  display: none;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas .div-forum-ideas-forum-card {
  margin-left: 5.32%;
  width: 43.40%;
  height: 49.84%;
 }

 .div-rectangle-main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -46px;
  background: linear-gradient(192deg, #3D4554 -10.36%, #242B36 45.63%, #1D1D1D 117.21%);
 }

 .div-rectangle-main .main-subtitle{
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 100px !important;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .div-rectangle-main .main-subtitle .main-subsubtitle{
  display: none;
 }

 .div-rectangle-main .main-title{
  padding-top: 10%;
 }
 
 .div-rectangle-main .main-logo{
  display: none !important;
 }
 
 .flexbox-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 26%;
 }
 
 .flexbox-container .card-home-main:nth-of-type(1){
  margin-top: -12% !important;
  margin-left: 6% !important;
 }
 
 .flexbox-container .card-home-main{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 7% !important;
  width: 91% !important;
  height: 160px !important;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas .div-forum-ideas-ideas-card {
  margin-left: 51.28%;
  width: 43.40%;
  height: 49.84%;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas-forum-card .section-icon-circle-forum-ideas-card {
  margin-top: 14.28%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  float: none;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas-ideas-card .section-icon-circle-forum-ideas-card {
  margin-top: 14.28%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  float: none;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas-forum-card .div-forum-ideas-card-title {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas-ideas-card .div-forum-ideas-card-title {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .div-forum-ideas-card-text {
  display: none;
 }

 
 .card-home-main .card-img{
  height: 0%  !important;
  width: 0% !important;
  margin-left: 3% !important;
  margin-top: 9% !important;
 }
 
 .section-icon-circle-card {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 90px !important;
  height: 90px !important;
  padding: 18px;
  margin-top: 0% !important;
  margin-bottom: 0% !important;
  margin-left: 0% !important;
  margin-right: 0% !important;
 }

 .card-home-main .card-info{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -7%;
  margin-left: 3%;
 }

 .card-home-main .card-title{
  position: relative;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: auto !important;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #2CC3D5;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .card-home-main .card-text{
  display: none !important;
 }
 
 .card-home-main .card-text-mobile{
  display: flex !important;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
  width: 55%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #3D4554;
 }

 .card-home-main .card-info .card-icon{
  display: none !important;
 }
}


.div-rectangle-main{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 100%;
 top: 492px;
 background: linear-gradient(192deg, #3D4554 -10.36%, #242B36 45.63%, #1D1D1D 117.21%);
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-logo{
 display: block;
 padding-top: 79px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0%;
 width: 250px;
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-title{
 font-family: Nunito Sans;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 800;
 margin-top: 36px;
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 55px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #2CC3D5;
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-subtitle{
 font-family: Nunito Sans;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 200px;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
 line-height: 200%;
 text-align: center;
}

.div-rectangle-main .main-subtitle .main-subsubtitle{
 font-weight: normal;
 
}


.flexbox-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: start;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main{
 width: 18%;
 margin-top: -9%;
 margin-left: 5.8%;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #EAEEEE;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.15);
 border-radius: 8px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 transition: 400s ease;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main:nth-of-type(1){
 margin-left: 0.8%;
}

.card-home-main .card-img{
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-top: 10%;
}

.section-icon-circle-card {
 border-radius: 100%;
 width: 108px;
 height: 108px;
 padding: 18px;
 margin-top: 4.95%;
 margin-bottom: 4.95%;
 margin-left: 6.42%;
}

.section-icon-circle-card--bot{
 background: rgba(44, 195, 213, 0.2);
}

.section-icon-circle-card--watermelon{
 background: rgba(246, 102, 137, 0.2)
 
}

.section-icon-circle-card--warning{
 background: rgba(255, 207, 51, 0.2);
}

.card-home-main .card-info{
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100% !important;
 padding-top: 0%;
 overflow: auto;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-title{
 font-family: Nunito Sans;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 line-height: 120%;
 color: #607B99;
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-bottom: 18%;
 text-align: center;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-icon{
 margin-left: 40%;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-text{
 display: none;
 
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main:hover{
 height: 420px;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main:hover > .card-info .card-icon{
 display: none;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main:hover > .card-info .card-text{
 display: block;
 font-family: Nunito Sans;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 line-height: 120%;
 color: #738192;
 width: fit-content;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 20%;
 margin-right: 20%;
 margin-top: -10%;
}

.flexbox-container .card-home-main:hover > .card-info .card-button{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0%;
 text-align: center;
 background: #2CC3D5;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: Nunito Sans;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 17%;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
 padding: 20px;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-text-mobile{
 display: none;
}

.card-home-main .card-info .card-button{
 display: none;
 
}
```

```html
      <div>
        <div class="div-rectangle-main">
            <h1 class="main-title"> Lore lore lore!</h1>
            <div class="main-subtitle">
             Lore lore lore
              <p class="main-subsubtitle">Lore lore lore lore =)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="flexbox-container">
              <div class="card-home-main" id="card1">
                <div class="card-img">
                <div class="section-icon-circle-card section-icon-circle-card--bot">
                    <img src="img/illustrations/Estrela-1.svg"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-info">
                  <div class="card-title">
                    <h3>B</h3>
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-text">Lore lore lore
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <BlipIcon name="arrow-ball-down-solid" class="bp-fs-1 bp-fill-bot"></BlipIcon> 
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-text-mobile">lore lore lore </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="card-home-main" id="card2">
                <div class="card-img">
                <div class="section-icon-circle-card section-icon-circle-card--watermelon">
                    <img src="img/illustrations/Estrela-2.svg"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-info">
                  <div class="card-title">
                    <h3>C</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <BlipIcon name="arrow-ball-down-solid" class="bp-fs-1 bp-fill-bot"></BlipIcon> 
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-text">lore lore lore lore </p>
                  <p class="card-text-mobile">lore lore lore 2 </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-home-main" id="card3">
                <div class="card-img">
                  <div class="section-icon-circle-card section-icon-circle-card--warning">
                    <img src="img/illustrations/Estrela-3.svg"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-info">
                  <div class="card-title">
                  <h3>D </h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <BlipIcon name="arrow-ball-down-solid" class="bp-fs-1 bp-fill-bot"></BlipIcon> 
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-text">lore lore lore </p>
                  <p class="card-text-mobile">lore lore lore2</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Cara edita a sua pergunta. Coloca exatamente o código que está usando no momento, vai facilitar para te responder

Comment: desculpa! Coloquei